# Set value to empty string (case statement)

Tags: sql

In my stored procedure, I have a case condition in my select statement.

Like this:

```
select Distinct col_1, col_2, col_3, Case when (ISNULL(char_01, 'M') = 'M') 
Then
.....
Else
End

From my_table
```

You can see that I have a column name `char_01`. Let say I want to replace `char_01` to 'M' then there is a `null` column. Also I want to replace `char_01` to 'M' when there is an **empty column** . So far I can only check the `null` column `(ISNULL(char_01, 'M') = 'M')` but I am not sure how to also check empty column.

I have tried:

```
Case when (ISNULL (char_01, 'M') = 'M') or //If char_01 is empty, then replace this column as 'M'
THen .... 
Else
end
```

I am stuck at the second part, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(char_01, ''), 'M')
```

If char_01 is empty NULLIF will return NULL and in turn ISNULL will pick up 'M'. If char_01 IS NULL NULLIF will still return NULL and ISNULL will again pick up 'M'. If char_01 is neither NULL or empty, both NULLIF and ISNULL will return its value.

[NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms177562.aspx)

Sample:

```
create table tbl (col1 varchar(5));
insert into tbl Values (''), (' '), (NULL), ('abc'), ('NULL');

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(col1, ''), 'M')
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. It works well.  :)

Comment: Just a question, what if my char_01 has NULL ? I don't think NULLIF allow null value in expression 1

Comment: @DragonBorn It does, if expression 1 is NULL and expression 2 is '', NULLIF will return NULL. See the sample code in my answer.